# Restricting access of a file server to a USB stick mounted at runtime

Tags: c++, linux, security, chroot, fileserver

I want to develop (C++) a file server process under linux which is able to provide clients access to the files on a mounted USB stick. It has to fullfil the following requirements during runtime:

- Client connections do not get access to any files while no USB stick is mounted.
- After mounting a USB stick, the access of all client connections is restricted to that USB stick. Access to any HDD files is not allowed.

As I understand, a standard way to confine the file access of a process would be to use *chroot*. However if I get it right, *chroot* would have to be executed before the process is started. At this point, the USB stick to which the access is to be confined is most probably not mounted yet.

So my question is: Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Ok, let me ask the outher way around. Would the best solution be to implement a file path filter mechanism inside the file server process to ensure that client access is restricted?